# Get stuck (in / on)

Tags: prepositions, verbs

**Edited:**

Could anyone let me know the correct preposition in the following cases after the verb [get stuck](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/get%20stuck)?

> 1.a. That was a difficult exam, but I got stuck **in** the third **question** which was truly difficult to answer. 
>   1.b. That was a difficult exam, but I got stuck **in** the third **question** which was truly difficult to answer.

Or

> 2.a. I got stuck **in** my **exam** when there were two options which looked similar. 
>   2.b. I got stuck **on** my **exam** when there were two options which looked similar.

Also, I am wondering if this verb is used in the same situations in AE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got stuck **in** a bad situation.

I got stuck **on** a question.

I got stuck **during** my exam.

By the way, your sentences are either strangely worded or totally incorrect even after we insert the correct preposition. *But* introduces a contradiction. The third question being difficult is not contradictory to the entire exam being difficult. Try:

> That was a difficult exam. I got stuck on the third question, which was truly difficult to answer.

You misused *which* when you should have you used *that*, and you didn't even finish the sentence. Try:

> I got stuck during my exam when there were two options that looked similar.